# Priority Queue add method modifies the all the elements with the last element added to it. Why?

Tags: java, hadoop, collections, priority-queue

/*In hadoop reduce method I am adding TopFrequency objects to the PriorityQueue.
Assume that I have getTotalCount method present in my reducer class.
totalCount is an instance variable of type DoubleWritable.*/

```
class TopFrequency{
    private double relativeFrequency;
    private WordPair wordPair;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TopFrequency arg0){
        int i=this.wordPair.compareTo(arg0.wordPair);
        if(this.relativeCount<arg0.relativeCount){
           return -1;
        }else if(this.relativeCount>arg0.relativeCount){
            return 1;
        }else if(this.relativeCount==arg0.relativeCount){
            return 0;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
class WordPair{
    private Text word;
    private Text neighbor;
}
class Reduce extends Reducer{
```

@Override
     protected void reduce(WordPair key, Iterable values, Context context) {
            double rCount=0.0;

```
        int count = getTotalCount(values);
        relativeFrequency=((double)count/totalCount.get());
        relativeCount.set((double) count / totalCount.get());

    //Creating an object of TopFrequency

        TopFrequency topFrequency=new TopFrequency(key, relativeFrequency);

    // All the references in reducerQueue point to   recently added object

        reducerQueue.add(topFrequency); 

       System.out.println("After adding to the queue "+reducerQueue);

    }
}
```

Comment: When you add a reference to an object, it doesn't copy that object.  If you keep adding the same object and then alter it, then it will look like all the values have changed but you have only changed one object.

Comment: I agree! But for each new key in the reduce method an entirely new object of TopFrequency is created and its reference is added to the queue. This code works when I am adding primitive data types to the queue instead of TopFrequency.

Comment: And all the objects it references are also new objects, or immutable.

Comment: All the objects are new objects because every time reduce is called a new object is being created due to this line TopFrequency topFrequency=new TopFrequency(key, relativeFrequency);

Comment: Where are you creating a new WordPair?

Comment: In the map method. WordPair is an instance variable of Mapper class. I am creating a WordPair object like this--------- WordPair wordPair=new WordPair(); wordPair.setWord("New"); wordPair.setNeighbor("York");